# How to approach writing unit tests for reformating

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I wrote a method that truns raw data into an object (JSON for all intents and purposes), it has several fields and sub-objects. Now that I want to write tests for it I'm stuck on how to approach it. It seems to me there is no other way than to repeat steps of my method and connect each field from raw data to the corresponding field in my desired object, to verify they are the same.
My question is whether this is the correct approach, are there any simpler ideas to utilize?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to discuss this if you posted some code of your current tests.

Comment: Depending on your unit testing or assertion framework, there might be something like "deep equals" checking that you can use to verify the entire object at once, instead of checking the fields one by one.

Comment: Deep equals does exist, though it can't verify that the value of the field came from the right place in the raw data, assuming that every bit of data isn't unique.

Comment: In a unit test, you control the input data, so you can make sure every bit _is_ unique. Also, keep in mind that the purpose of unit testing is not to prove 100% correctness; the purpose is to catch as many bugs as early as possible.